# Are CSS selectors case-sensitive?

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-selectors

I was recently updating a CMS site and a tab-navigation plugin had inserted the following markup:

```
<li id="News_tab">...
```

I've always written my CSS selectors in lowercase so when I tried to style this with `#news_tab`, it wouldn't apply, but `#News_tab` worked.

After all these years I'm surprised that I haven't run into this before, so I've always been under the impression that CSS was case-insensitive. Has CSS always been case-sensitive and I just haven't noticed thanks to my consistent code style?

Comment: don't use caps to start out class or id attributes. personally, i don't use them at all, except for camel casing JS classes.

Comment: @albert Yes, I wouldn't use caps either... it was generated by a plugin, not my style.

Comment: Make sure you use a DOCTYPE or you could get weird behavior!!!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

CSS itself is case insensitive, but selectors from HTML (class and id) are case sensitive:

[CSS recommendation on case sensitivity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters)

[HTML recommendation, id attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id) (note the [CS])

Answer (score 15):

**CSS4 ([CSS Selector Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-case))** adds support for case-insensitive match (ASCII only).

`input[value='search' i]`

It's the "i" at the end which would do the trick...

Check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26721521/825924) for details which browser supports this.

Answer (score 6):

Class and ID attributes are case sensitive.

Comment: I like this line: *The simplest way to mitigate any potential issues surrounding case sensitivity is to always use lowercase for everything in your markup and CSS.*

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html

> All CSS syntax is case-insensitive within the ASCII range (i.e., [a-z] and [A-Z] are equivalent), except for parts that are not under the control of CSS

From the docs website.

---

Follow-up for selectors:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

> The case-sensitivity of document language element names in selectors depends on the document language. For example, in HTML, element names are case-insensitive, but in XML they are case-sensitive.

Comment: As was mentioned, CSS isn't case sensitive but HTML does impose restrictions.