# IE9 Suddenly CSS Case Sensitive

Tags: css, internet-explorer

For some reason, CSS has all of a sudden become case sensitive in IE9. I have tried this on other peoples computers and the site displays fine in IE9, but on my machine it wont display CSS unless the case is right.

I can change IEs settings this to quirks mode and it will work, but it doesn't explain the strange behavior.

I have tried resetting all IE's settings back to default, clearing cache, but was not able to reinstall it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you in standards mode? Historically IE has been case-insensitive for the class and ID selectors, but I understand IE9 is case-sensitive when in standards mode.

CSS properties and most values are case-insensitive, exceptions being `url()` where the webserver serving up images might have case-sensitive filenames.

CSS selectors are case-insensitive except for parts outside of CSS, such as `#id` and `.class` selectors. For more information see this question: [Are CSS selectors case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559205/are-css-selectors-case-sensitive)