# Hover not working on disabled option in internet explorer

Tags: css

I am working on a page where I need to add some style on hover of disabled option(in a select tag).

I have tried below css but none of them is working in internet explorer.

**Code:**

```css
 select>option:disabled:hover {
        color:green;
    }
    
    select>option:hover([disabled]) {
     color:orange;
    }
```

```html
     <select size=8 multiple>
      <option disabled>5<option>
      <option>10<option>
      <option>15<option>
      <option>20<option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Try making everything lowercase. IE is known to be very case sensitive.

Comment: @MistaPrime Citation needed.

Comment: still not working..

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't mention `disabled`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602140/how-to-style-disabled-options-in-a-form That question might help you.

Comment: @MrLister There have been reports of it on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557948/ie9-suddenly-css-case-sensitive

Comment: @MistaPrime Seriously, the case sensitivity of class and id names in quirks mode has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: thanks @SimonBrahan but its not working for hover of disabled option

Comment: the question you referred does not even contain text "disabled " @dippas ..

Comment: If you just take the HTML you have shown, and try to set a color for the disabled option via IE dev tools, even that is not working (it accepts the style, but it doesn’t show any effect) … so my guess would be that this is simply not supported by IE at all.

Comment: okay @04FS. can't we use javascript to achieve this?

Comment: JavaScript is not going to convince IE to apply styles it wouldn’t apply if they were set directly. You can either replace your select field completely with a custom HTML implementation (select2 or similar), or you could try to _emulate_ the effect of `disabled` via JS (don’t set the actual attribute, but immediately de-select the option again, if it gets selected by the user.)