# PHP give tag id of its contents

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a variable which consists of diffrent html tags:

```
$html = '<h1>Title</h1><u>Header</u><h2>Sub Title</h2><p>content</p><u>Footer</u>'
```

I want to find all the u tags in the $html variable and give them the id of their contents.

It should return:

```
$html = '<h1>Title</h1><u id="header" >Header</u><h2>Sub Title</h2><p>content</p><u id="footer" >Footer</u>'
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: use an HTML parser instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace()` if you want it fast way, or learn about [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php) if you want to do it the proper way.

```
$pattern = '~<u>([^<]*)</u>~Ui';
$replace = '<u id="$1">$1</u>';
$html = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $html);
```

Comment: OP wants the id's in lower case, yours are in upper case!

Comment: @Rizier123 In HTML, attributes' values are case insensitive. Same goes for CSS selectors.

Comment: `<style type="text/css">#x{background-color:#000000; color:#E0E0E0 }</style>
 <div id="X">sdfsdf</div>
 <div id="x">sdfsdf</div>` See the difference ? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7559251/3933332 And id is a selector!

Comment: @Rizier123 I see you spam without even testing. What you posted here is just proof to statement of mine - `id`s and CSS selectiors are **case insensitive**

Comment: ^ Copy my example and say me if both div's has a black background?

Comment: ^ Did you read my posted SO answer related to this and read the CSS recommendation ? Here you have the link directly to it: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#adef-id

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace.

```
$html = preg_replace('~<u>([^<]+)</u>~e','"<u id=\"".strtolower("$1")."\" >$1</u>"', $html);
```

The e means "evaluate", which allows you to cram the "strtolower" command into the replacement.

Comment: `e` is deprecated! Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

it will be good to do it using `jquery` if it suits your need else Forien answer is good to go

`here it goes to do it in jquery`

your html

```
<div id='specialString'>
    <h1>Title</h1><u>Header</u><h2>Sub Title</h2><p>content</p><u>Footer</u>
</div>
```

your js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#specialString > ul').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).text());
    });
</script>
```